# WebSphere 7 Server is not starting in java 8 Eclipse Luna

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, websphere-7, eclipse-luna

I installed WebSphere 7 in my system and Java 8 version. I am using Eclipse Luna and added was 7 plug in in eclipse and tried to start server, but server was not starting.

What i need to do?

**[6/22/15 11:18:39:977 IST] 00000000 WsServerImpl E WSVR0009E: Error occurred during startup com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeError: org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL: CREATE_LISTENER_FAILED_4 vmcid: 0x49421000 minor code: 56 completed: No**

```
 at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ORBImpl.start(ORBImpl.java:438)
 at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.startComponents(ContainerHelper.java:538)
 at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.startComponents(ContainerImpl.java:627)
 at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.start(ContainerImpl.java:618)
 at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:502)
 at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.bootServerContainer(WsServerImpl.java:298)
 at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.start(WsServerImpl.java:214)
 at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.main(WsServerImpl.java:666)
 at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServer.main(WsServer.java:59)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:45)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
 at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.launchMain(WSLauncher.java:213)
 at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:93)
 at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.run(WSLauncher.java:74)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformActivator$1.run(PlatformActivator.java:78)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:92)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:68)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:177)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:45)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
 at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:340)
 at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:282)
 at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:981)
 at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.launchEclipse(WSPreLauncher.java:341)
 at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.main(WSPreLauncher.java:111)
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL: CREATE_LISTENER_FAILED_4 vmcid: 0x49421000 minor code: 56 completed: No

 at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTransport.createListener(WSTransport.java:866)
 at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTransport.initTransports(WSTransport.java:604)
 at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.TransportManager.initTransports(TransportManager.java:151)
 at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ORB.set_parameters(ORB.java:1231)
 at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB.set_parameters(ORB.java:1681)
 at org.omg.CORBA.ORB.init(ORB.java:364)
 at com.ibm.ws.orb.GlobalORBFactory.init(GlobalORBFactory.java:92)
 at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSORBImpl.initializeORB(EJSORBImpl.java:179)
 at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSServerORBImpl.<init>(EJSServerORBImpl.java:102)
 at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSORB.init(EJSORB.java:55)
 at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ORBImpl.start(ORBImpl.java:431)
 ... 29 more

[6/22/15 11:18:39:899 IST] 00000000 FfdcProvider W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on D:\IBM\WAS_Installation\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\ffdc\server1_6880688_15.06.22_11.18.39.83645038.txt com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTransport.createServerSocket 1387 [6/22/15 11:18:39:930 IST] 00000000 FfdcProvider W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on D:\IBM\WAS_Installation\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\ffdc\server1_6880688_15.06.22_11.18.39.89945039.txt com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTransport.startListening 805 [6/22/15 11:18:39:977 IST] 00000000 FfdcProvider W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on D:\IBM\WAS_Installation\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\ffdc\server1_6880688_15.06.22_11.18.39.93045040.txt com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTransport.createListener 724 [6/22/15 11:18:45:156 IST] 00000000 SchedulerServ I SCHD0040I: The Scheduler Service is stopping. [6/22/15 11:18:45:156 IST] 00000000 SchedulerServ I SCHD0002I: The Scheduler Service has stopped. [6/22/15 11:18:45:172 IST] 00000000 AppProfileCom I ACIN0009I: The application profiling service is stopping. [6/22/15 11:18:45:172 IST] 00000000 ActivitySessi I WACS0049I: The ActivitySession service is stopping. [6/22/15 11:18:45:172 IST] 00000000 ObjectPoolSer I OBPL0011I: The Object Pool service is stopping. [6/22/15 11:18:45:187 IST] 00000000 distSecurityC I securityServiceStarted is false [6/22/15 11:18:45:203 IST] 00000000 CGBridgeServi I CWRCB0103I: The core group bridge service has stopped.
```

**[6/22/15 11:18:51:865 IST] 0000000e SSLHandshakeE E SSLC0008E: Unable to initialize SSL connection. Unauthorized access was denied or security settings have expired. Exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?**

```
 at com.ibm.jsse2.b.a(b.java:36)
 at com.ibm.jsse2.pc.a(pc.java:292)
 at com.ibm.jsse2.pc.unwrap(pc.java:20)
 at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:17)
 at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.readyInbound(SSLConnectionLink.java:535)
 at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.ready(SSLConnectionLink.java:295)
 at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
 at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
 at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
 at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
 at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
 at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
 at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
 at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
 at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
 at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1646)

[6/22/15 11:19:26:715 IST] 0000000e SSLHandshakeE E SSLC0008E: Unable to initialize SSL connection. Unauthorized access was denied or security settings have expired. Exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

 at com.ibm.jsse2.b.a(b.java:36)
 at com.ibm.jsse2.pc.a(pc.java:292)
 at com.ibm.jsse2.pc.unwrap(pc.java:20)
 at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:17)
 at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.readyInbound(SSLConnectionLink.java:535)
 at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.ready(SSLConnectionLink.java:295)
 at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
 at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
 at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
 at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
 at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
 at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
 at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
 at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
 at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
 at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1646)
```

**. [6/22/15 11:20:01:597 IST] 0000000e SSLHandshakeE E SSLC0008E: Unable to initialize SSL connection. Unauthorized access was denied or security settings have expired. Exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?**

```
at com.ibm.jsse2.b.a(b.java:36) at com.ibm.jsse2.pc.a(pc.java:292) at com.ibm.jsse2.pc.unwrap(pc.java:20) at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:17) at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.readyInbound(SSLConnectionLink.java:535) at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.ready(SSLConnectionLink.java:295) at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214) at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113) at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165) at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217) at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161) at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138) at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204) at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775) at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905) at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1646)
```

Comment: WebSphere Application Server v7 doesn't support running with Java 8. It can only be used with the provided java which as I recall is Java 6.

Comment: 1.then for java 8 which version of was will support? 
2. is there any official confirmation that java 8 wont support was 7.
3. Was 7 is supported by java 7 also but you are saying only java 6 !

Comment: @saideshkilaru If you look at the log header at the top of SystemOut.log, does it actually show that the server is using Java 8?  This error almost always means you have a port conflict.  I suspect the server is running using the version of Java that the product installs, and the failure has nothing to do with your installation of Java 8.

Comment: @saideshkilaru 1. there is no version of WAS Classic that supports Java 8. WAS Liberty does as of 8.5.5.5. 2. The support site for WAS v7 says Java 6. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=180&uid=swg27012421 3. The WAS server provides and runs with Java 6 as per the link for 2. As bkail says your problem is probably a port conflict, not a Java version issue.

Comment: Does java7 support was7??

Comment: No, WebSphere v7  comes with its own (IBM) Java 6. Using external Java 6,7 or 8 is not supported. Java that you use with Eclipse has nothing to do with Java used by the app server.